# Firebase Realtime Database Rules don't work for new users

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have the following rules for my Firebase Realtime Database:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$user_id": {
        ".read": "auth !== null && auth.uid == $user_id",
        ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid == $user_id",
        ".validate": "data.hasChildren(['calculations', 'daily', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'monthly', 'profileImageUrl', 'uid', 'username', 'weekly'])",
        "calculations": {
          ".validate": "data.isNumber()",
        },
        "daily": {
          ".validate": "data.isNumber()",
        },
        "firstName": {
          ".validate": "data.isString()",
        },
        "lastName": {
          ".validate": "data.isString()",
        },
        "monthly": {
          ".validate": "data.isNumber()",
        },
        "profileImageUrl": {
          ".validate": "data.isString()",
        },
        "uid": {
          ".validate": "data.isString()",
        },
        "username": {
          ".validate": "data.isString()",
        },
        "weekly": {
          ".validate": "data.isNumber()",
        },
        "$other": {
          ".validate": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Old Firebase Realtime Database Rules that worked for new users:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.uid == $user_id",
    ".write": "auth.uid == $user_id"
  }
}
```

Firebase Authentication with email and password:

```
// Firebase Authentication to create a user with email and password
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            val user = auth.currentUser
            // Send an email verification to the user. Only allow them to login after they
            // have verified their email.
            user!!.sendEmailVerification().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    // Save username, first name, and last name on Firebase Database
                    val uid = auth.uid ?: ""
                    val ref = database.getReference("/users/$uid")
                    val newUser = User(uid, userName, firstName, lastName, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3, "")
                    ref.setValue(newUser)

                    Toast.makeText(
                        this,
                        "Please check your inbox and verify your email address.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                    val intent = Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
                    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK.or(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
    .addOnFailureListener {
        Toast.makeText(
            baseContext, "Failed to create an account: ${it.message}",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show()
    }
```

User class:

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
data class User(
    val uid: String,
    val username: String,
    var firstName: String,
    var lastName: String,
    val daily: Double,
    val weekly: Double,
    val monthly: Double,
    val calculations: Int,
    val profileImageUrl: String
)
```

These rules work for existing users. But if I try to create a new user, these rules don't work. I can't create new data in my database for new users that have signed up. How do I fix this?

Comment: It's impossible to say how to change the rules without seeing the code that exercises them. Please edit your question to include the minimal code that now gets rejected by these rules, that you want to be accepted.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have included the minimum code used that I want the rules to accept.

Comment: If you log the value of `uid` right after you get it with `val uid = auth.uid ?: ""` what is the output? Also: this is one of those cases where using a `?:` operator is actually hurting you. Your code assumed `uid` is not empty, so you should not convert `null` to `""` there but instead fail if `uid` is still `null.`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen The output of `uid` is the new user's ID. `uid` is not empty and this code worked before the changes to my database rules. I changed the rules to enhance security but if I revert back to my less secure rules, the rules don't work for new users who just signed up.

Comment: "my less secure rules" We have no way to know what those are, so can't make any comment around them. Note it would also help if you could pinpoint the problem to a specific property, as it's quite error prone for us to visually check each property.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have included the old Firebase Database rules that worked for new users. Currently, my Firebase Database is empty. I don't how to go about pinpointing the problem to a specific property.

Comment: OK. So based on those previous rules the problem is not in the authentication but in the validations you added.  I recommend disabling the validation rules, and then one by one reenabling them and testing again until you've found the one that fails. At worst that should lead to a smaller problem for us to look at, but you might find the cause of the problem on your own while isolating it.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen So I removed the validations and it worked. When I added at least one of the validations (the `firstName` validation), it no longer worked. It looks like there's an issue with my validations and I can't pinpoint what it is. I've looked at documentation and it seems like I've done it the correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you need to validate that the new data is the correct type. So:

```
"calculations": {
  ".validate": "newData.isNumber()",
},
```

If you check the Firebase documentation on [validating data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#validaterules) you'll see that they also all check `newData` instead of `data` (which refers the to data *before* the write operation).